# Deciding if a gmail conversation's emails belong or not to certain labels / folders

Tags: php, .net, gmail, imap

I need to go through a gmail **conversation** and check if ALL of the emails that belong to this conversation , serve certain criteria.

Example: "Show me all the conversations that all emails reside ONLY in sent items and trash"

I am open to *any* solution in PHP, .NET (ASP.NET/Winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses a non-standard extension, the [`X-GM-THRID`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_thread_id_x-gm-thrid) for their conversations stuff. Using that, and somehow having obtained the `X-GM-THRID` of the relevant thread, you can simply use that in the IMAP's `SEARCH` command. Google also uses the "all messages" mailbox which contains all messages for your account and the [`X-GM-LABELS`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels) for finding out to which of the IMAP folders that message is mapped.

See [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) for how to use the `AND` operator in `SEARCH` and just combine the keys mentioned above. The result is easy to use in any IMAP library.